# String variable will not display is will not display in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jframe

The variable `String` **result** will not display in the `JPanel` **outpanel**, when I run this program. Can someone tell me why ? I have tried googling and experimenting with `static` etc for hours but I believe `static` is not OO-Friendly as an answer even if it did solve it.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class AProgram extends JFrame 
            implements WindowListener, ActionListener  {

    public JButton gbt = new JButton("GO");
    public JPanel outpanel = new JPanel();
    public ArrayList<String> responses;
    public String result;

    public AProgram() {
        super ("Program");
    }

    public void init() {
        //output
        outpanel.setOpaque(true);
        outpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 75)); 
        outpanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 2));       
        JLabel jl = new JLabel();    
        jl.setText(result);
        outpanel.add(jl);
        this.add("South", outpanel);

        //press-button - does NOT sit in a panel.
        gbt.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        gbt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 75));
        gbt.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 2)); 
        this.add("East", gbt);

        //all
        gbt.addActionListener(this);
        this.addWindowListener(this);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt) {
        String input = "A Lion is ";
        finishSentence(input);
    }

    public void windowClosing (WindowEvent e) {
        this.setVisible(false);
        this.dispose();
    }

    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}

    public String finishSentence(String inwds) {
        responses = new ArrayList<String>();
        responses.add(0, "a bookish creature");
        responses.add(1, "quiet and unassuming");
        responses.add(2, "King of the Jungle");

        String result = inwds + responses.get(2);

        return result;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        AProgram me = new AProgram();
        me.init();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a logical & consistent code formatting style!  The code indentation is intended to help people follow the program flow.

Comment: Please do remember, instead of overriding `WindowListener` methods, one can simply use `frameInstance.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`, for the same effect, that you trying to achieve, in `windowClosing()` method. This 1 line is equivalent to those 10 lines :-)

Answer (score 3):

in your `init()` method you set the text of `jl` to result which is `null`.

then in your `actionPerformed()` you invoke the method `finishSentence()` which returns a `String` but you did not assign it to any variable or element.

call the `jl.setText()` again in your `actionPerformed()`

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt)  {

        String input = "A Lion is ";

        jl.setText(finishSentence(input));                                        

        }
```

Comment: :D (as well as making my JLabel classlevel data) It works. Oh my gosh Thank you. I have been stuck on this for like 3 hours. !